# Adding list of products to a non sales order

Tags: netsuite

Sales-Orders are a built in record type. I am trying to make a custom record type that has a list of items similar to that of a sales-order. Without having to create much custom HTML/JS code is there a way to add this functionality to a custom record type?

I've looked into Parent-Child relationships between records and that looks promising but requires a fair bit of learning on my end and before I invest that time I'd like to know if that is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can achieve this depending on whether you want sales order like extra fields associated with an item line.

The simplest way would be to include a multi-select custom field referencing item on your custom record. This will give you an item selection box and you can associate  items with the custom record.

If that's sufficient then do that and you're good to go.

However if you want details associated with each item (like quantity) you'd need to create a custom line record as well as your custom transaction record.

The line record would have the original custom record as a parent record (custom field type List/Record referencing the parent record and check the "Is Parent" checkbox on the field definition page. 
The line record would also need a custom list/record field that references items.

Standard UI forms will now let you add custom line records to your parent record and let you select items and add whatever extra fields you need at the line level.

All configuration; no code.

When you look at the custom parent records though you won't see your custom lines right away because they are under the 'custom tab' you can edit the custom parent record's forms and move the custom sublist to the top of the form's sublists so when you open a custom parent record the associated child line records will be on the first tab.